# undefined method `developers_path' , Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I get the below error when I try to invoke the page.

http://localhost:3000/developer/new

[image]

The content of the views/new.html.erb file is as follows:

## Create Developer

```
<%= form_for(@developer) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name  %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit "Create Developer" %>
<% end %>
```

The contents of the developer_controller.rb are as follows:

```
class DeveloperController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @developer = Developer.new
  end
end
```

The contents of the routes.rb file as below:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #get 'admin_controller/home'

  get 'admin_controller/help'

  #get 'create_developer' => 'admin_controller#new'

  resources :developer
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: For faster responses, make sure to follow the Rails naming conventions, it should be developersController, plural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
resources :developer
```

To:

```
resources :developers
```

In config/routes.rb then restart the rails server.

And change your controller
From `class DeveloperController` to `class DevelopersController`